# Как отцентровать меню

Tags: bootstrap, menu

Как отцентрировать элемент меню. Ищу поведение по типу `pull-right`, однако класса `pull-center` не нахожу.

Answer (score 1):

поместите его в контейнер и сделайте контейнеру margin:0 auto;

Comment: сайт вот http://cinemart.mirnsp.by/ - пока делаю на поддомене но так отступ не проходит

Comment: сделано как я понял на bootstrap?

Comment: http://bootstrap-ru.com/ тут описаны все приёмы с адаптивными меню, и всем остальным

Comment: у вас в меню прописано свойство float:right; уберите его и сможете отцентрировать

Comment: пользуйтесь фаербагом в мозиле-очень удобно.

Comment: float убрал а отцентровать все равно не получается ни маржином